# Localized resources not loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, globalization

I have an application in ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 with localized satellite assemblies installed by NuGet to show pt-BR validation messages downloaded in:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.pt-br/

It works and loads all pt-BR localized strings in my development environment, but when I publish in one of our servers the messages still showed in en-US.

The screenshot bellow shows some information about MVC Version and Culture and UI Culture:

[image]

It seems that the resource dll wasn't loaded, but, the application is running in pt-BR culture.

The resource DLL System.Web.Mvc.resources.dll is found in /bin/pt-BR folder.

The web.config globalization section is configured:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="false" />
```

Anyone has an idea?

bin directory content list:

> \bin\Antlr3.Runtime.dll
>   \bin\Autofac.dll
>   \bin\Autofac.Integration.Mvc.dll
>   \bin\Autofac.Integration.WebApi.dll
>   \bin\AutoMapper.dll
>   \bin\AutoMapper.Net4.dll
>   \bin\BootGridMvc.dll
>   \bin\CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll
>   \bin\EntityFramework.dll
>   \bin\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>   \bin\MyApp.Core.Business.dll
>   \bin\MyApp.Core.Data.dll
>   \bin\MyApp.Core.Models.dll
>   \bin\MyApp.Core.Report.dll
>   \bin\MyApp.Web.Mvc.dll
>   \bin\itextsharp.dll
>   \bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll
>   \bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll
>   \bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll
>   \bin\Microsoft.Owin.dll
>   \bin\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll
>   \bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll
>   \bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll
>   \bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll
>   \bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll
>   \bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll
>   \bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll
>   \bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll
>   \bin\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
>   \bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>   \bin\Owin.dll
>   \bin\Portable.Licensing.dll
>   \bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
>   \bin\System.Web.Helpers.dll
>   \bin\System.Web.Http.dll
>   \bin\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll
>   \bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll
>   \bin\System.Web.Optimization.dll
>   \bin\System.Web.Razor.dll
>   \bin\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
>   \bin\System.Web.WebPages.dll
>   \bin\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
>   \bin\T4MVCExtensions.dll
>   \bin\WebGrease.dll
>   \bin\pt-br
>   \bin\pt-br\System.Web.Mvc.resources.dll

Comment: Please list the entire contents of your `bin` directory, including all subfolders. You should have a localized satellite-assembly: `bin\pt-BR\yourSite.dll`.

Comment: I don't have a resource in my site, I just use a resource of System.Web.Mvc for MVC validation messages. My site is entirely in pt-BR. Do I need rename this dll? System.Web.Mvc.resources.dll

Comment: It works in all development machines of my team, even in Debug and Release modes and Published in local IIS, with Windows in portuguese and english. But only when I publish in one of our servers and in customer server it doesn't works.

Comment: Do you have the 'Copy Local' field set to 'True' under your references in Visual Studio for the pt-br dll? It likely works in local due to the dll existing on the local machine.  The client/production server does not have a copy of the dll and falls back to the english version.  Just a guess.

Comment: Yes, System.Web.Mvc have the 'Copy Local' field set to 'True'. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841541/how-to-add-satellite-assemblies-to-a-project-in-visual-studio, the satellite assemblies are copyed with the referenced assembly, and I can see in bin/pt-br/ folder the resource DLL after build.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a stupid suggestion, but make sure that you reference the localized resource dll's in your .nuspec file so that they are actually included when you package the NuGet bundle.